# How to add multiple directories to Xscreensaver?

Tags: directory, xscreensaver

What i learned from reading man page for xscreensaver [MAN page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xscreensaver-getimage.1.html) that i will have to edit .xscreensaver under my home directory. In here there is option to set directory set with option

> imageDirectory:

I want to know is there any way i can add multiple directories to show in the screensaver

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question, but after configuring one directory (running `xscrennsaver-demo`, no need to edit manually .xscreensaver), you can create symbolic links (with `ln -s`) to all other images in other directories you would like to be read by the screensaver.